# Avoid SSH key being moved

Tags: security, ssh, key

I want to set up an SSH gateway for me and a couple of others.
Being authorized with this gateway server, should mean access to any target server.

This is so far easily done by installing a public key into all target servers, and placing the non-password SSH key in all users home directory on the gateway server.

However I don't want anyone to be able to take the SSH key with them. It should be locked onto the gateway server, and not viewable by other than the SSH and SCP client utilities to authorize with targets.

Is there any possible way to secure the private key, kind of like good old DRM locking software to a given PC?

Thanks!

Comment: You can specify an encryption password on the key to allow only authorized users to use it. You may also want to consider good ol' Unix permissions. :)

Comment: an SSH key is just a file. If people have the right to read and use it, they can also copy it. Think about what you're asking here. What you *can* and should do however is generate separate keys for every user. If somebody logs into your machine then, you can at least be sure who it was. Also, you can revoke single keys that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're focusing on a means, not an end.

When you say you don't want users "to be able to take the SSH key with them", you really mean you don't want users to be able to log in to the destination machines without going through the gateway server. Because who cares if they have the key if it doesn't do them any good?

So, make the key be authorized only for logins with a source IP of the gateway server (on the destination machines to which it provides access). See [this reference](http://linux.m2osw.com/ssh_authorize_keys_features), specifically the `from` directive. Naturally, you also have to change the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive in the global `sshd_config` to include somewhere the users can't write on the destination machines (it allows multiple paths, so you don't have to stop them from adding their own keys, but it sounds like you want to). Then, so long as users of the gateway server sharing keys with each other isn't an issue - that is to say, anyone who can log in to the gateway should have the key - and your network prevents source-IP spoofing to the destination machines, you're fine.

You may also want to reconsider the approach you're using; if the purpose of the gateway server is *just* authentication (single sign on and centralized access control), you'd be better off using a distributed authentication method like Kerberos instead of a clunky log-in-here-to-get-in-there method.